# Tweet Strings via Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to automatically tweet a list of URLs. However if my list is too long (it can vary from tweet to tweet) I am not allowed. Is there anyway that tweepy can create a thread of tweets when the content is too long? My tweepy code looks like this:

```
import tweepy

def get_api(cfg):
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cfg['consumer_key'], 
cfg['consumer_secret'])
  auth.set_access_token(cfg['access_token'], 
cfg['access_token_secret'])
  return tweepy.API(auth)

def main():
  # Fill in the values noted in previous step here
  cfg = { 
    "consumer_key"        : "VALUE",
    "consumer_secret"     : "VALUE",
    "access_token"        : "VALUE",
    "access_token_secret" : "VALUE" 
    }

  api = get_api(cfg)
  tweet = "Hello, world!"
  status = api.update_status(status=tweet) 
  # Yes, tweet is called 'status' rather confusing

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Could you update your question to demonstrate how you are tweeting a list of URLs? Is this a string list of URLs, or a list of strings? In any case, if you know max permissible length, just check length before tweeting. If tweet to send is greater than max length, chunk to a list and send each chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't relevant to the problem you're trying to solve. Not only does `main()` not seem to take any arguments (tweet text?) but you don't show how you are currently trying approaching the matter. Consider the following code:

```
import random

TWEET_MAX_LENGTH = 280

# Sample Tweet Seed
tweet = """I'm using tweepy to automatically tweet a list of URLs. However if my list is too long (it can vary from tweet to tweet) I am not allowed."""

# Creates list of tweets of random length
tweets = []
for _ in range(10):
    tweets.append(tweet * (random.randint(1, 10)))

# Print total initial tweet count and list of lengths for each tweet.
print("Initial Tweet Count:", len(tweets), [len(x) for x in tweets])

# Create a list for formatted tweet texts
to_tweet = []
for tweet in tweets:
    while len(tweet) > TWEET_MAX_LENGTH:

        # Take only first 280 chars
        cut = tweet[:TWEET_MAX_LENGTH]

        # Save as separate tweet to do later
        to_tweet.append(cut)

        # replace the existing 'tweet' variable with remaining chars
        tweet = tweet[TWEET_MAX_LENGTH:]

    # Gets last tweet or those < 280
    to_tweet.append(tweet)

# Print total final tweet count and list of lengths for each tweet
print("Formatted Tweet Count:", len(to_tweet), [len(x) for x in to_tweet])
```

It's separated out as much as possible for ease-of-interpretation. The gist is that one could start with a list of text to be used as tweets. The variable `TWEET_MAX_LENGTH` defines where each tweet would be split to allow for multi-tweets.

The `to_tweet` list would contain each tweet, in the order of your initial list, expanded into multiple tweets of <= `TWEET_MAX_LENGTH` length strings.

You could use that list to feed into your actual tweepy function that posts. This approach is pretty willy-nilly and doesn't do any checks for maintaining sequence of split tweets. Depending on how you're implenting your final tweet functions, that might be an issue but also a matter for a separate question.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I know my question was kind of vague.